# Filter JavaRDD into multiple JavaRDD based on Condtion

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, rdd

I have one **JavaRdd records**
I would like to create **3 JavaRdd** from records depending on condition:

```
JavaRdd<MyClass> records1 =records1.filter(record -> “A”.equals(record.getName()));
JavaRdd<MyClass> records2 =records1.filter(record -> “B”.equals(record.getName()));
JavaRdd<MyClass> records13=records1.filter(record -> “C”.equals(record.getName()));
```

The problem is, that I can do like I show above, but my records may have millions record and I don’t want to scan all records 3 times.
So I want to do it in one iteration over the records.

I need something like this:

```html
records
 .forEach(record -> {
  if (“A”.equals(records.getName()))
  {
   records1(record); 
  }
  else if (“B”.equals(records.getName()))
  {
   records2(record); 
  }
  else if (“C”.equals(records.getName()))
  {
   records3(record); 
  }
 });
```

How can I achieve this in Spark usin JavaRDD?

Answer (score 1):

In my idea you can use "MapToPair" and new a Tuple2 object in each of your if condition block. Then your key in the Tuple2 will help you to find each rdd objects type. In other words, Tuple2s key shows the type of the objects you wanted to store in one rdd and it's value is your main data.

your code would be something like below:

```
JavaPairRdd<String,MyClass> records1 =records.forEach(record -> {
    String key = "";
    if (“A”.equals(record.getName()))
    {
        key="A";
    }
    else if ("B".equals(record.getName()))
    {
        key="B";
    }
    else if ("C".equals(record.getName()))
    {
        key="C";
    }
    return new Tuple2<>(key, record);
});
```

the resulting pairrdd objects can be divided by different keys you have used at foreach method.